# Visualizing High Dimensional Data in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize a dataset with more than 30 (all numerical) features in Python , bringing them down to 2 or 3 dimension so that I can use a Cartesian Plane. I tried PCA but the results aren't that good probably because the explained variance of the first 3 loading vectors is under 50%. Does anyone knows other alternative techniques?

Comment: Here is a good overview of alternatives: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html

Comment: Thanks for the help!